# Move Navigation bar to right in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I've been trying to move the navigation bar in bootstrap4 to the right side of the screen by using float: right; on the nav a and it just is not doing anything. I'm using a codepen app to write my code for a project I'm doing.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<class="row">
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">About</a>
<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">Portfolio</a>
<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">Contact</a>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css');

nav a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Can you provide the codepen?

Answer (score 0):

its working fine, just add **float: right !important;** in your CSS

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css');

nav a {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: right !important;
}
```

here is the pen: [Working Example (CodePen)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjBVPX)

Comment: Would you happen to know why the lists change order when I float the links to the right in bootstrap? It doesn't do that in regular CSS.

Comment: You might be missing something or your css class/id is not inheriting properly or some other ambiguities in your code, there can be tons of problems it would be great if you post your code both HTML & CSS. @JamesVelardi